# Image element same size as window: closed

Tags: html, css, image, device-width

I would like to have an image on my html site that is the same width of the site.
I have obviously used the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` but the image still doesn't change size.

I've even tried some css, but it is only one size: same size as computer, to big for a tablet or phone.

Any help for it?

Could JavaScript help?

Comment: please add your example code ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to include a [mre] as that will help to increase the quality of the answers you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use viewport unit to do that.

```css
img {
   display: block;
   width: 100vw;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='' style='width: 100%; object-fit:cover'/>
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From Review.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the width of the image to 100%. Example:

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Or if you want it to be the background image of the page, you can use the background-image element. Example:

```css
body {
    background-image: url(your image name);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I am not sure, if this is going to work or not. At least, you can try.